# .htaccess not working with same name and same alias of .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I on virtual host in my local ubuntu system host name is `moffer.loc` and I am tying to match url `moffer.loc/offer/some-slug-text`. but it not work with `offer` keyword, if I try with other than `offer` like `offers`, `offer-info` than it works.

My `.htaccess` file is :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^offer/(.*)$    /offer.php?slug=$1 [QSA,L]
 </IfModule>

DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm login.php /access_denied.html
```

When is Use `RewriteRule ^offers/(.*)$    /offer.php?slug=$1 [QSA,L]` then it works fine. but why ?
I don't know why I can not use only `offer` ? it works when I use other text than `offer` but I must need to use `offer` alias

Comment: Can you update your question to show the sorts of incoming URLs you are trying to match?

Comment: It works for me on http://htaccess.mwl.be/ . For input `http://example.com/offer/offer` I get an output `http://example.com/offer.php?slug=offer` maybe you have other conflicting `.htaccess` entries

Comment: change the file name as `offers.php` than try `offer`

Comment: @tim I update my question

Comment: @Mojilo it's still working for me. is that your only rewrite rule? You may be double triggering it.

Comment: @devor and @apokryfos ohhh.. when I change `offer.php` to `offers.php` than its works fine... but why ? now it woks `http://moffer.loc/offer/abcd-xyz`

Comment: What exactly does "not work" mean? What is happening?

Comment: @deceze "not work" ** "now it works", sorry typo in my comment

Comment: Is it possible this is just a case of `offers.php` is a real file while `offer.php` is not?

Comment: no I rename file name, offer.php to offers.php, than i try `offer` in .htaccess. now its works

Comment: maybe conflict with the same file name.

Comment: yes, when I use same name whatever is file name and alias, Its conflict and not working.